# Equivalent definition of Markov property

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I would like to prove that stochastics process $\left\{X_t\right\}_{t\in T}$ holds Markov property if and only if for each $t,s_1,s_2\in T$ such as $s_1<t$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t-s_1}X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)= \mathrm{E}\left(X_{t-s_1}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)\quad a.s.
\end{align}

I can prove that if stochastics process  $\left\{X_t\right\}_{t\in T}$ holds Markov property then
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t-s_1}X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)= \mathrm{E}\left(X_{t-s_1}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)\quad a.s.
\end{align}

The reason is that if the stochastic process holds Markov property then for each Borel mesurable function we have
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left(f(X_{t+s_2})|\sigma\left(X_l; l\leq t\right)\right)=\mathrm{E}\left(f(X_{t+s_2})|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)\quad a.s.
\end{align}

So if we take $f=id$, we have

\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_l; l\leq t\right)\right)=\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)\quad a.s.
\end{align}
Then we can write down that

\begin{equation}
\label{pod1}
\begin{aligned}
\textstyle\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t-s_1}X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_l; l\leq t\right)\right)&=\textstyle X_{t-s_1}\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_l; l\leq t\right)\right)=\\
\textstyle &=X_{t-s_1}\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)\quad a.s.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Finally we get

$\begin{aligned}
\textstyle\mathrm{E}\left[\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t-s_1}X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_l; l\leq t\right)\right)|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right]&=\textstyle\mathrm{E}\left[X_{t-s_1}\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_l; l\leq t\right)\right)|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right]=\\
&=\textstyle \mathrm{E}\left[X_{t-s_1}\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right]=\\
&=\textstyle \mathrm{E}\left(X_{t-s_1}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right).
\end{aligned}$

On the other hand if we use tower property, we have
\begin{align*}
\textstyle\mathrm{E}\left[\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t-s_1}X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_l; l\leq t\right)\right)|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right]&=\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t-s_1}X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right).
\end{align*}

So if we put these two expression together we have
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t-s_1}X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)=\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t-s_1}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right) \quad a.s.
\end{align*}

But I cannot deal with the other implication. It means I do not know how to prove that if the
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t-s_1}X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)= \mathrm{E}\left(X_{t-s_1}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)\quad a.s.
\end{align}
holds then stochastic process  $\left\{X_t\right\}_{t\in T}$  is Markov. I wolud like to show that for each Borel measurable function holds equation
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left(f(X_{t+s_2})|\sigma\left(X_l; l\leq t\right)\right)=\mathrm{E}\left(f(X_{t+s_2})|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)\quad a.s.
\end{align}
Or I would like to show that
\begin{align}
\label{MR vlastnosť}
P\left(X_{t+s}\in B|\sigma(X_l; l\leq t )\right)=P\left(X_{t+s}\in B|\sigma(X_t)\right)\quad a.s.
\end{align}
holds for each Borel set $B$ and each $t,s\in T$.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The converse cannot hold, take a process with trajectories that are equal to a random constant $Z$, so $X_s \equiv Z, s \in T$. Then knowing $X_t$ for some $t \in T$, you know $X_s$ for all times $s \in T$, so
$$
\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t-s_1}X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)= Z^2 = \mathrm{E}\left(X_{t-s_1}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)\mathrm{E}\left(X_{t+s_2}|\sigma\left(X_t\right)\right)\quad a.s.
$$